# How to find last deleted files on OpenSuse?

Tags: files, opensuse, data-recovery, audit, trash

I didn't lock the screen on my OpenSuse Linux and let my girlfriend do all evil things when I was sleeping. Is there a way to find out if she deleted any files from my PC?

I was looking at the "Date Modified" timestamp of my folders and then I tried to delete something and that date didn't change. I was also looking at logs in `/var/log`, but I don't know where exactly to look and also haven't found anything.

I think she deleted files by moving them to the trash can and then emptying the trash can and I think that this procedure will be in some log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't work with OpenSuse, but as I know, there is no logs on *trashcan*.

But if content of a directory change, His modification time have to change too.

At all, there is a few possibility to restore something, but:

- You have to stop immediatly your disk activity (in root: `mount -o remount,ro /home` if */home* is the mountpoint of partition)
- You have to know what you want to restore, there is a few tools for doing that job, but you have to inform them about what to search for.
- If `/` (root) is *the* partition to work on, you have to use another way, like live-usb in order to be able to work on read-only partition.
- Preferably copy whole partition to another before of working on.

Modifying *Trashcan* behaviour to ask him to make log is possible too, but this depend on which desktop environment you are using.

There are essentially two widely used `file-manager`:

- nautilus on gnome
- konqueror on kde

I use nautilus. Running `gconf-editor`, searching for *trash* (including key names), there are no *log*, nor *empty trash command*. So if you're using gnome's `nautilus`, there are 2 ways:

- using `inotify` (`inotifywait`) for monitoring the gnome's trash directory, than moving every new entry to a hidden directory, before `empty trash` could be run by user.
- patching nautilus from source for adding such a feature. (Or pay a programmer to do this) and send your modif to nautilus's maintener as a suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I am in fact using openSUSE, but @F.Hauri is basically right.

Files, which have actually been totally deleted (from trash) are not logged. I guess you run a standard set-up, so the file-system should be something like ext3 or ext4. There are a number of tools, which can scan your file-system for the remains of deleted files, e.g. http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/ 
This will find a number of files, even very old stuff, in case they have not been overwritten by other files.